# Not able to render react component

Tags: reactjs, database, react-hooks

I am working with a React project and getting data from a database. I am able to get the data properly and also store in the array, but while I am rendering a component using the array data, the component is not getting displayed. I am not able to understand what is going wrong. I have attached the code below.

```
const [postItems, setPostItems] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const getPostData = async () => {
        try {

            await api.getData().then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
                res.forEach((doc) => {
                    setPostItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, {
                        "location": doc.location,
                        "date": doc.date,
                        "text": doc.experience
                    }])
                })
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }
    getPostData()
    console.log(postItems)

}, [])
```

I am rendering post component and passing the array(postItems) values as props. But the post component is not getting rendered.

```
  {postItems.forEach((element) => {
                    <Post location={element.location} text={element.text} date={element.date} />
                })}
```

Also I console logged postItems array, this is what I am getting,which is correct.

```
[
{
    "location": "Pune",
    "date": "2021-10-30",
    "text": "Great trip"
},
{
    "location": "Pune",
    "date": "2021-10-26",
    "text": "Content"
},
{
    "location": "Pune",
    "date": "2021-10-29",
    "text": "Wonderful experience"
}
```

]

Comment: I haven't tested your code, but I think instead of using foreach, you should use map and if you are using brackets you should add the return statement, otherwise it won't return anything. If you want to omit return keyword, you should place that code in one line or add parentheses

Comment: Ya, that's right. That was the issue, I was missing the return statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyze the problem,

First, you need to understand that your **setState()** function is async, and calling it continuously inside a *forEach* loop which is synchronous in nature is causing you to get wrong results.

```
const [postItems, setPostItems] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const getPostData = async () => {
        try {

            await api.getData().then((res) => {
                const stateData = []; // make a temporary const to store your state to be set
                res.forEach((doc) => {
                    stateData.push({
                        "location": doc.location,
                        "date": doc.date,
                        "text": doc.experience
                    });
                });
                // finally set your state here
                setPostItems([...stateData]);
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }
    getPostData();

}, [])
```

The second problem lies within the snippet where you are mapping every state element to

Add a return statement like below,

```
{postItems.map((element) => {
                    return <Post location={element.location} text={element.text} date={element.date} />
                })}
``
```

Comment: Your second note regarding the return is correct. Your first is half-right - the function returned from useState is not instant in so far as the results are not immediately displayed, but the way that OP uses useState - by passing a function to useState - will work just fine, even if it's not the best way to do things. See [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-waterfall-8o73i?file=/src/App.js) for an example. It would not be accurate to call the set state handler from useState "asynchronous" - it's synchronous. OP's problem is the lack of return in their render function's forEach.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I did realize that the same data for getting pushed in the array repeatedly.

Comment: @Dan You're right and wrong in a way, if you tell that `setState` handler from `useState` is synchronous, it's actually the batching which is based on the  version of `setState`  used, here `archie09` is using the callback version which promises to give the latest updated state but had it been the standard version of setState then things would look different. see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-lumiere-w8g65?file=/src/App.js)
---
Thanks for pointing that out!! That was really insightful. 

Comment: `useState`/`setState` are both *synchronous*. The state update itself is *asynchronous*, which is why you should pass a function to either (you can do this with `setState`). Calling a function async in js implies that you can `await` it or that it returns a promise, so we should be careful with doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a return statement before the Post component to explicitly return the component or remove the curly brackets and put parenthesis.

You should also return the forEach or alternatively using map that has an implicit return

```
    {postItems.map((element) => (
        <Post location={element.location}
            text={element.text} date={element.date} />
     ))}
```

Comment: Ya, I was missing the return part. Thanks for pointing that out. Even though while using map I still have to return the component

Comment: Yeah, with map you can avoid to use `{return postItems.forEach ...}` :)